# Getting oauth token using Jmeter xpath extractor

Tags: xpath, jmeter, extractor

What should be the Xpath query if I want to extract the value for access token, ie 93ee29b4-74dc-4uu7-8e10-6eac6845511b from below http response. I tried using the Xpath extractor with different xpath queries, but no luck.

```
{
  "access_token":"93ee2tum-1234-56789-8e10-6eac684551tum",
  "token_type":"Bearer",
  "expires_in":3600,
  "scope":"test"
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any reason you are using the xpath extractor instead of the regular expression extractor? Xpath is only useful in case there are for example multiple identical tags with different values.

Regular extractor:
access_token":"([^"]+)"

If you do need to use xpath you should know that it doesnt work with Json by default. 
Read also: http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-xpath-extractor-jmeter-0

Comment: Thanks Johan, Regular extractor with access_token":"([^"]+)" worked for me.